# Draw "bitmap" font on C# graphics

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts

I have problem with drawing TrueType font to graphics. The font have been created with [Raster font editor](http://www.cylog.org/graphics/rasterfonteditor.jsp) and converted to TrueType just simply changing the extension from .fnt to .ttf. I know that isn't the best practise but Windows installed it. However I can't draw this font to graphics. I've tried draw him with simple:

```cs
Font fnt = new Font("Bitmap Font", 8);
```

but also with embedding the font in applications resources.

To the end I should say that the Windows form is inside MonoGame project.

Thank you for answers!

Comment: _However I can't draw this font to graphics._ What happens? Also: Can you use that Font in other applications?

Comment: @TaW I've never tried it but I could try Monogame.Forms instead

Comment: I've tried it with calibri font and worked so there must be problem with Raster font editor export. Anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: `PrivateFontCollection` says that there aren't any font families

Comment: Is your font contained in `System.Drawing.FontFamily.Families` ?

Comment: @grepfruit no but i've installed it. It's weird because Word and Microsoft Paint shows this font.

Comment: You didn't mention what exactly happens, as TaW inquired. In case the problem is only with drawing the font, the issue might be with .NET drawing methods using Windows' GDI+ vs. using GDI. GDI+ is actually pickier when working with fonts than GDI is. Try drawing like so: `using (Font font = new Font("Bitmap Font", 24, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel))
{
    Point point1 = new Point(30, 10);
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "Hello", font, point1, Color.Blue);
}`